# delay function on publish?

Tags: plugins, actions

I have this function where I call a custom function through the add_action hook:

`add_action('publish_post', 'custom_function');`

... now it works perfectly, but the I want the custom_function to be delayed so it runs AFTER the post has been published.

BUT, if I add `sleep(20)` inside the `custom_function` it delays the post itself. What I want is the post to be published, and THEN run this function after x seconds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`publish_post` is called after post is published! So, you already got covered. but if you want to run an action after a certain time of the post is published, it's better to write a cron job.

For example, if you need to run the function after 5 minutes of the post is published, you need to register a single cron event that will be triggered after 5 minutes from now (post publish)

```
add_action('publish_post', 'register_single_cron');

function register_single_cron($id){
  wp_schedule_single_event(tim() + 300, 'custom_function');
}

function custom_function(){
  //your logic goes here
}
```

Please check the api details [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event).

But this system has one problem, it will not be triggered until site is loaded/visited on or after the scheduled time.

Comment: ah, visiting the site is a strange requirement. :( any other workarounds?

Comment: i do not see any easy workaround! all the alternatives i've in my mind are more complicated :s